# MySQL Creating a Database CentOS (6 - 64bit) Error 1064 (42000)

Tags: mysql, vps, database, centos6, database-administration

When ever I type in :

`GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES minecraft.* TO 'minecraftu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '********';`

---

It gives me an error of :

`ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'minecraft.* TO 'minecraftu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '********'' at line 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the word `ON`.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON minecraft.* ....
```

Comment: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON minecraft.* TO 'minecraftu'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '*********';`

Still didn't work.

Comment: So what was the error, then?

Comment: Sorry nevermind, I just had to restart PUTTY. Thank you for your help.